# Can I exclude files from an NPM package on the installation side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

Is it possible to exclude files from a list of NPM packages in my `package.json`?

I have a non-browser environment that works a bit differently: every file in `node_modules` dir becomes part of the production package. So there's no smart treeshaking that imports only the files that I use in my code.

For instance, I use some packages which also carry a lot of tests and i18n files, most of which I don't need and like to remove from my packaged production version. However, they are still included in the end package because the whole package folder is included in the build.

I'm trying to remove as many files from the packages as I can (without doing it manually each time) to save space and compilation time. The environment I use is looping all files in the `node_modules` directory and adds them to the production package (all packaged using Javascript). I would like a JavaScript solution to remove these files on compilation so the end package is as small as it can be.

Comment: Is this for server-side nodejs packages or client-side packages that you are including in a web app?

Comment: client side packages like for instance numeraljs/momentjs/mustache/backbone

Comment: *"I would like a JavaScript solution to remove these files on compilation so the end package is as small as it can be."* If you bundle your JavaScript, then it will only contain the files that are dependencies of the code you import. Any other files in the packages that are not direct dependencies (tests or CSS files usually are not), won't be included.

Comment: _If you bundle your JavaScript, then it will only contain the files that are dependencies of the code you import._ where does this originate from? say i get https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeral using npm; no matter how i put it, the `tests` directory will remain in the package. It will be there when I package my project

Answer (score -4):

I would use [bower](http://bower.io/) to manage client-side javascript modules, instead of using npm directly.

Bower packages are simpler than npm equivalents and don't have subfolders with module dependencies.  Most will include a "dist" folder with pre-minified javascript.  Right out of the box your packages will be smaller than if you use npm.

If you want to go further, you can include some processing in your gulpjs or gruntjs scripts to either manually copy needed files to `lib` and `css` folder(s), or use a plugin like [gulp-bower-normalize](https://github.com/cthrax/gulp-bower-normalize) to (somewhat) automatically do the same thing.

Comment: umm yea using bower instead of npm is like saying drink pepsi instead of coca cola. Not to mention that packages used are literally the same. Its an extension package manager which doesnt do much out of the box. for instance, the `bower.json` file contains a `main` key which points to the main js-file, but its not that its automagically selected as "copy this file over when we are in production env".

I think its main difference is the directories in which packages are placed by default.

Comment: Bower is deprecated now :)